# MarkerClusterer is not coming up in my Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm trying to achieve using this, why am I not able to get that using this. I've tried this put my markers in array as you can find my `var markers` is defined as array and the finally I've tried to output it by using `var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`

This I've used for reference http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/docs/examples.html

Where it is mentioned:

> Once you create a marker cluster, you will want to add markers to it.
>   MarkerClusterer supports adding markers using the addMarkers() method
>   or by providing a array of markers to the constructor:

[image: My Map Preview]

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/24wfR/

Below mentioned is my code for achieving this

```
function createMarker(latlng, i, tran_store_id) {
    var storeMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latlng,
        icon: storeMarker,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        labelContent: (i + 1),
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 40),
        labelClass: "store-custom-labels label_" + (i) + "_no",
        // the CSS class for the label
        labelInBackground: false
    });
    marker.set("id", i);
    //console.log(Drupal.settings.store.themepopup[tran_store_id]);
    var myOptions = {
        content: Drupal.settings.store.themepopup[tran_store_id],
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-142, -379),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {
            width: "500px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "6px -161px 0px 0px",
        closeBoxURL: Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/close.gif",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
        enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "click");
        for (var i = 0; i < totalMarkerCount; i++) {
            var giconsc = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
            markers[i].setIcon(giconsc);
            jQuery('.label_' + i + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        }
        var val = marker.get("id");
        jQuery("div.search-result-item").removeClass("active");
        jQuery("#" + val).addClass('active');
        jQuery('.label_' + val + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        var gicons = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(55, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
        marker.setIcon(gicons);
        ib.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function () {
        var val = marker.get("id");
        if (!jQuery('#' + val).hasClass('search-result-item active')) {
            jQuery('.label_' + val + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function () {
        var val = marker.get("id");
        if (!jQuery('#' + val).hasClass('search-result-item active')) {
            var gicons = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
            marker.setIcon(gicons);
            jQuery('.label_' + val + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(ib, "closeclick", function () {
        ib.close();
        var val = marker.get("id");
        jQuery("#" + val).removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.label_' + i + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        var gicons = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
        marker.setIcon(gicons);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        ib.close();
        var val = marker.get("id");
        jQuery("#" + val).removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.label_' + i + '_no').css('color', '#ffffff');
        var gicons = new google.maps.MarkerImage(Drupal.settings.store.module_path + "/images/marker.png", new google.maps.Size(50, 60), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(0, 50));
        marker.setIcon(gicons);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
```

Comment: For each new marker you created another MarkerClusterer.

Comment: Where I've created another MarkerClusrerer, or can you please help me with the solution?

Comment: in function createMarker()

Comment: I'd create cluster after for loop which calls createMarker() function.

Comment: Anto, I've changed the position but it didn't got affected, placed it after 
function createMarker(latlng, i, tran_store_id) {
}
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

Comment: [fiddle using MarkerClusterer(Plus)](http://jsfiddle.net/HwJK8/).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [Anto Jurković](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2452708/anto-jurkovic)

Answer was pretty clear and many thanks again for that!

Create **cluster** after for **loop** which calls **createMarker()** function. Hence I've done the same thing, called the `var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);` just after my loop gets finished where I've called the `createMarker()`

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
    address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    timings = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("timings");
    size = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("size");
    phone = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("phone");
    getaddress = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("getaddress");
    tran_store_id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("tran_store_id");
    sidebar_entry = '<div id=' + i + ' class="contact_content"><div class="top"><em>' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name") + '</em><br /> ' + address + '</div>';
    if (phone != '') {
        sidebar_entry = sidebar_entry + '<div class="btm"> ' + phone + '</div>';
    }
    sidebar_entry = sidebar_entry + '</div>';
    jQuery('#stores_list').append(sidebar_entry);
    createMarker(latlng, i, tran_store_id);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    var viewlist = document.getElementById(i);
    viewlist.onclick = function () {
        selectMarker(this.id);
        jQuery("#stores_list.div").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    };
    totalMarkerCount = i;
    j++;
}
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```